# Get confused by JS for loop output

Tags: javascript

I have a block of code:

```js
const calculatenumbers = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var myindex = i;
  calculatenumbers.push(() => {
    var calculatednumber = myindex * 100;
    console.log('my number is:' + calculatednumber);
  });
}



for (var j = 0 ; j < calculatenumbers.length; j++) {
calculatenumbers[j]();
}
```

the output of this code is:

```
my number is:500
my number is:500
my number is:500
my number is:500
my number is:500
```

Why the code output five times 'my number is:500'
instead of

```
my number is:100
my number is:200
my number is:300
my number is:400
my number is:500
```

Comment: I don't see (nor expect) any output for this code on the Chrome console. You're just pushing a function inside the array and not calling that function.

Comment: I've updated the question, please review it again.

Comment: `var` is hoisted so the value of `myindex` is `5` for every function call.

Comment: Replace `var myindex = i` with `let myindex = i` and it will work as you intended.

Comment: You could pass the index as an argument, like this:

    const calculatenumbers = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      calculatenumbers.push((myindex) => {
        var calculatednumber = myindex * 100;
        console.log('my number is:' + calculatednumber);
      });
    }

    for (var j = 0 ; j < calculatenumbers.length; j++) {
      calculatenumbers[j](j);
    }

Comment: @Andy `push` accepts anything, it simply takes whatever it gets and adds it to the array.

Comment: @Andy, an array can hold anything. You're just pushing a function in place of primitive variables.

Comment: Your current code would work if JS was asynchronous and ran on one thread.

Comment: @ kindall Can I ask why the index is 5 when the callback function is called, shouldn't be the case that each time the callback is called, it receives the corresponding index (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Answer (score 0):

you can use let, don't use var in loop function

```js
const calculatenumbers = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let myindex = i;
  calculatenumbers.push(() => {
    var calculatednumber = myindex * 100;
    console.log('my number is:' + calculatednumber);
  });
}



for (var j = 0; j < calculatenumbers.length; j++) {
  calculatenumbers[j]();
}
```